# How to programmatically route inside a component - Vue Router

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have a Quasar app running Vue 3 with vue-router 4

My routes are setup and work great when navigating from a component template with

```html
<router-link to="/route">Go to route</router-link>
```

I want to be able to access the router and route from my methods though. According to the docs I should be able to get access to the router object somehow, this.$router, or router, or some other way... but I can't seem to gain access

My entire single file component looks something like

```html
  <template>
    <q-page>
      <q-card>
        <q-form @submit="handleSubmit()" >
          <q-input v-model="param" />
          <q-btn label="submit" type="submit" />
        </q-form>
        <router-link to="/">Go to Foo</router-link> <!-- this works great -->
      </q-card>
    </q-page>
  </template>

  <script lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  export default {
    setup () {
      const param = ref(null);
      return { param }
    },
    methods: {
      async handleSubmit () {
         // do stuff
         // route somewhere
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

How can I access the vue router from my handleSubmit method?

`this.$route` and `this.$router` are undefined, and as I understand with vue 3 and sfc this pattern doesn't apply. For my store for example I need to use vuex `mapState` and `mapActions`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type inference for the Options API requires [declaring components with the `defineComponent()` wrapper](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components):

> To let TypeScript properly infer types inside Vue component options, you need to define components with `defineComponent` global method:
>
> ```js
> import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
>
> const Component = defineComponent({
>   // type inference enabled
> })
> ```
>
> If you're using [single-file components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html) then this would typically be written as:
>
> ```html
> <script lang="ts">
> import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
>
> export default defineComponent({
>   // type inference enabled
> })
> </script>
> ```

So your component should look similar to this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
                    
export default defineComponent({
  methods: {
    async handleSubmit () {
      // ✅
      this.$router.push('/')
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Alternatively, you can use [`useRouter()` in the Composition API](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#accessing-the-router-and-current-route-inside-setup):

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const handleSubmit = async () => {
      router.push('/')
    }

    return { handleSubmit }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<template>
    <q-page>
      <q-card>
        <q-form @submit="handleSubmit()" >
          <q-input v-model="param" />
          <q-btn label="submit" type="submit" />
        </q-form>
        <router-link to="/">Go to Foo</router-link> <!-- this works great -->
      </q-card>
    </q-page>
  </template>

  <script lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  export default {
    setup () {
      const param = ref(null);
      return { param }
    },
    methods: {
      async handleSubmit () {
         this.$router.push('/link/to/go/anywhere') <-- here
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: I tried all manner of this.$router but always get `Property '$router' does not exist` :(

Comment: Are you using `vue-router`  as plugin ? If not i will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

do you forgot to set the router-view --> tag it should be in App.vue  in your template so it render your component data into your router and yes use this.$router.push({ path: '**your router path**' }) in your method

Comment: What if you want this to be in another child component and not in App.vue?